# What is the minimum weekly pay to be credited with a Qualifying Year on your National Insurance?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, national-insurance

I run a limited company, and want to pay myself a wage. There is a limit to what you can pay yourself before the company has to pay National Insurance contributions. But what is the minimum wage you can pay yourself in order to get a Qualifying Year on your National Insurance record (for State Pension purposes)?

Comment: `credited with a full years national insurance` What do you mean ?

Comment: @DumbCoder presumably, enough contributions to make a Qualifying Year for state pension purposes?

Comment: Assuming this is the intent behind the question I've edited it accordingly and will post an answer.

Comment: @marktristan that's correct, do you know what the minimum salary is to qualify for a year on your National Insurance record!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gov.uk website makes this very difficult to find out, so your question is understandable.

For an employee, if you're earning a wage of more than £166 a week (2019/20) you will pay Class 1 National Insurance contributions (12% on the amount above that). Carry these on for a full year and that should make one Qualifying Year.[[1]](https://www.gov.uk/national-insurance/how-much-you-pay)

However – if you earn **between £118 and £166 a week**, although you don't actually pay Class 1s, your contributions are *treated as having been paid to protect your National Insurance record*. [[2]](https://www.gov.uk/national-insurance)[[3]](https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/savings/state-pensions/#ni)

So the short answer is **£118 a week**, or **£6,136 a year**.

The only true way to know whether you have a Qualifying Year is to [check your own National Insurance record](https://www.gov.uk/check-national-insurance-record) after the fact, and you can make [voluntary contributions](https://www.gov.uk/voluntary-national-insurance-contributions) to 'top up' if you have not quite made enough for a Qualifying Year.

There is a lot more information on qualifying here – including conditions for whether or not you have an NI record before 2016:
https://www.nidirect.gov.uk/articles/understanding-and-qualifying-new-state-pension

Comment: While this is correct based on the numbers, I paid myself £9909.63 for the 2018/2019 tax year and I didn't get a full NIC year (shortfall of £483.45 by the website). I'm not sure why -- as we don't see those calculations -- but there might be something else as well that affects this (?).